# laravel eloquent to get specific relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i'm trying to get result from pivot table(classe_categorie) using

```
$categories = Course_category::has('classe')->get();
```

which match the classe_id of user id

```
$classe_id = Auth::user()->classe_id;
```

i have tried

```
$categories = Course_category::whereHas('classe', function ($query) {
    $classe_id= Auth::user()->classe_id;
    return $query->where('classe_id', '=', $classe_id);
})->get();
```

but it shows me result with different classes

Comment: Pivot table `course_category` should not have a model representation, it's a pivot table

Comment: Try changing this `$query->where('classe_id', '=', $classe_id)` to `$query->where('id', '=', $classe_id)`

Comment: Can you show your models showing the relationship?

Comment: @Doro   `public function classe(){ return $this -> belongsToMany('App\Classe','classe_categorie','categorie_id','classe_id')->withPivot('course_name','image','categorie_id','classe_id','course_id','hash_name','description','exercice','correction');
        }`

Comment: @N69S yes he has no model